# Ha sido imposible ejecutar la acción Grabar: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, postgresql

Dear friends of the forum:
I'm learning the book Learn OpenXava OpenXava by examples.

I'm done with the first part of Invoicing project, but I can think of a problem to insert a detail in Invoice entity.
Dear friends of the forum:
I'm learning the book Learn OpenXava OpenXava by examples.

I'm done with the first part of Invoicing project, but I can think of a problem to insert a detail in Invoice entity.
The error message is as follows:
"Unable to run the Record action: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement".

Instead of using PostgreSQL, use MySQL (my engine works on port 3307). And OpenXava is version 5.3

Primary keys of both the Invoice Details entity as the entity are generated with the "uuid" strategy.

Copy the configuration file context, persistence and hibernate.cfg.xml
to see if we clarify something.

Context.xml:

```
<Resource auth="Container driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"    maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/OpenXavaTestDS" password="" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1555" username="sa"/>

<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/MySchoolDS" password="" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:../data/my-school-db" username="sa"/>

<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/InvoiceDemoDS" password="" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:../data/invoice-demo-db" username="sa"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/reclamosDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="plexo" driverClassName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/reclamos"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/InvoicingDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="plexo" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/invoicing"/>
```

The persistence.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence &lt;a href=" http:="" java.sun.com="" xml="" ns="" persistence="" persistence_1_0.xsd"="">http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="default">
<non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/InvoicingDS</non-jta-data-source>
<class>org.openxava.session.GalleryImage</class>
<properties>

<property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="junit">
<properties>

<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

<property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/invoicing"/>

<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>

<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="plexo"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the hibernate.cfg.xml code:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">



<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>


<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java://comp/env/jdb/InvoicingDS</property>
<property  name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">false</property> 
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>




<mapping resource="GalleryImage.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thank you in advance for your kind attention.

Greetings to all.

Comment: Put the complete stacktrace, the code of your entity and table structure, please. Maybe the table and the entity does not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear friends of the forum:

He's solved the problem.

The same occurred because one of the exercises in a column called "ID" is added, which then was replaced by another called "OID"; unclear that it should delete the first.
This I should have inferred, but I missed it.

By eliminating the "Id" column, the problem was solved.

Thank you for your attention.